# How to eliminate all the unicode that are higher than 12000 in VBA?

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA, what should I write in VBA to remove all the unicode that are higher than 12000?
For example,

Text:
 購買保險指南อของเabc

Expected Result:
購買保險指南อของเabc

Comment: All of these are higher than 12000:   購買保險指南

Comment: @drgs: Maybe he is talking about hex values?

Comment: I think he means 120 000. Anyway, you could use RegExp, but I don't know how to address unicode characters with more than 4 unicode digits, ie. \u00000... Would probably need to loop through all individually.

Comment: can you provide the full code? as i am new to excel vbA